# Apache Benchmark timeout and 14648 errors

Tags: apache, testing, load, benchmarking

When running the apache benchmarking below:

```
ab -n 1500 -c 150 http://yourdomain.com/
```

I am getting the following error, and the benchmarking is stopped with only a limited number of requests completed:

```
apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
```

Also, at other times when I run the same ab command I get the following error:

```
apr_sockaddr_info_get() for yourdomain.com: Unknown error: 14648 (14648)
```

How can I get the test to complete?

Comment: Could you print your output? Are you really using "http://yourdomain.com"? Is it correct? Trying typing `hostname` in your console and check your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Hi Lucy, how did you resolve this error? If you remember.